# How do I access the last cell of dynamic table to get the total

Tags: javascript

I am calculating the total from a table on the last column input

Currently the alert for `td` shows `[Object Nodelist]`

```js
function calcTotal() {
            var table = document.getElementById("invoice_details");
            //var tot = 0;
            var tot=$("#service_cost").val();
            //alert(tot);
            var sumvval=0;
            var table_length=table.rows.length;
            //alert(table_length);
            var td = document.querySelectorAll('#invoice_details > tbody > tr > td:last-child');
            //var val = document.querySelector('#invoice_details tbody tr td:last-child input').value;
            alert(td[0]);
            var total=0;
            for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++)
            {
                total += parseFloat(td[i].innerText);
            }
            total=total+parseFloat(tot);

            document.getElementById("total_invoice_amount").value = parseFloat(total);

        }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="invoice_details">
    <tbody id="generate_invoice_table">
    <tr>
    <td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="57" name="item_id[]"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="Toyota" name="supplier_name[]"></td>
    <td><input hidden="" class="form-control" readonly="" value="Item" name="type[]"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="Fan Belt Aqua" name="item_description[]"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="1" name="available_qty[]"></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" readonly="" value="12000.00" name="retail_price[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" class="form-control text-right" name="qty[]" onmousemove="calcTot(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" class="form-control text-right" name="discount[]" onmousemove="calcTot(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control text-right" name="price[]"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would help if you made a code snippet with a mocked-up table that recreates the problem. What do you get if you do `alert(td[0]` ?

Comment: Please create a stack snippet (https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or at least JSFiddle for such questions

Comment: [object HTMLTableCellElement]. I have a input in last cell i want to get the total for all the input's in this dynamic table. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a array and you are using in table then you can simply get the last value from dynamic table.

```
var last = array.length -1 ;
console.log("Last value ::: ", array[last]);
```

Comment: anyway to use the same code, with querySelectorAll?

Comment: Please check this link. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp